# Django - Migration foreign key field type not matching current type

Tags: python, sql-server, django, django-migrations

I am working with MSSQL database and I have some tables that were already created before Django enters the show, so with *inspectdb* I got the models with `managed=False` Meta option. Then I create others that work with Django migrations. This models are something like this:

```
class ModelAlreadyCreated(models.Model):
    # This PK field is set as varchar(16)
    id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, db_column='CVE', max_length=16)
    ...other fields

    class Meta:
        managed=False

class DjangoModel(models.Model):
    model_ac_fk = models.ForeignKey(ModelAlreadyCreated)
    ... other fields
```

When I create the migrations file using `makemigrations` I get this:

```
migrations.CreateModel(
        name='DjangoModel',
        fields=[
            ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
            ('model_ac_fk', models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to='ModelAlreadyCreated')),
            ...
        ],
    ),
```

Until this point everything seems ok, but with the `migrate` command this error is shown:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1778, "Column 'CVE' is not the same data 
type as referencing column 'model_ac_fk' in foreign key 'model_ac_fk_fk_CVE'.DB-Lib error 
message 20018, severity 16:\nGeneral SQL Server error: Check messages from 
the SQL Server\nDB-Lib error message 20018, severity 16:\nGeneral SQL Server 
error: Check messages from the SQL Server\n")
```

This error comes out because Django is trying to create a `nvarchar(16)` foreignkey field and the actual referenced field is `varchar(16)`

I can get the SQL using `sqlmigrate` and alter the field types, then run it directly in the DB and Fake the migration, but I want to know if there is any way to make the migration using Django without touching any SQL script?

Comment: Can a table with primary key of type `varchar(16)` be created in MSSQL by Django? It is an important information for reasoning that it is supported.

Comment: I think Django creates nvarchar fields for CharField model.field and not varchar, AFAIK the only way for creating a varchar field in Django is defining a CustomField.

Comment: I think also that it is the biggest problem that is not noted in the question. What about to experimentally convert on a database copy the primary key to something supported, e.g. UUIDField? I expect that you can not do it really because old tables are frequently shared by something, but it can demonstrate if a migration failed or if the required state is impossible with the current driver anyway.

Comment: Hello, did you find any solution for this? I'm facing a similar issue in the Microsoft SQL Server.