# Django migrate column is not the same data type as referencing column

Tags: sql-server, django, django-models

I have the below model which is an existing DB model and through Django's inspectdb management command the below model is created.

```
class ExistingLegacyModel(models.Model):
    period = models.TextField(db_column="Period", blank=True, null=True) 
    key = models.AutoField(db_column="OutlookKey", primary_key=True)
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = "table_name"
```

and currently, I'm trying to create a model with a field foreign key reference to the existing legacy DB model

```
class TestModel(models.Model):
    period = models.ForeignKey(
        ExistingLegacyModel,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        db_column="OutlookKey",
    )
```

so when I run the makemigrations command the migration file is successfully getting created with no issue. below is the migration file content.

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    initial = True

    dependencies = [
        ('historical', '0011_phoenixcontractprice'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='TestModel',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.BigAutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('period', models.ForeignKey(db_column='OutlookKey', on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to='app.ExistingLegacyModel')),
            ],
        ),
    ]
```

so now when i run the migrate command now, it is failing and giving the below error.

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Column 'table_name.OutlookKey' is not the same data type as referencing column 'version_testmodel.OutlookKey' in foreign key 'version_testmodel_OutlookKey_eb16c31c_fk_table_name_OutlookKey'. (1778) (SQLExecDirectW); [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors. (1750)")
```

I'm stuck with this issue for the past couple of days and I searched all over the internet but didn't get any resolution. I found a couple of StackOverflow questions that are very similar to my issue, but those questions are also unanswered.

1. [Django - Migration foreign key field type not matching current type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46498186/django-migration-foreign-key-field-type-not-matching-current-type)
2. [Django 3.2 update AutoField to BigAutoField backward compatibility with foreign key relations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69993873/django-3-2-update-autofield-to-bigautofield-backward-compatibility-with-foreign)

I'm currently using Django 3.2.13 and mssql-django to connect to the MSSQL database.

Any help on this will be highly appreciated! Thank you in advance.

**UPDATE 1**

I ran the sqlmigrate command for the initial migration. So for the period column, it is creating the table with a foreign key field with big int `[OutlookKey] bigint NOT NULL` whereas the existing legacy model has a normal integer field.

```
ALTER TABLE [<app>_<model>] ADD CONSTRAINT [<app>_<model>_OutlookKey_3505d410_fk_<existing_legacy_table>_OutlookKey] FOREIGN KEY ([OutlookKey]) REFERENCES [<existing_legacy_table>] ([OutlookKey]);
```

Comment: Well, what's the actual data type of `table_name.OutlookKey`?

Comment: Hello @aaron, it's an AutoField. In the question I have added the model generated by inspectdb command. So in the database table datatype is int

Comment: I guess the issue is related to Django 3.2 assigning bigint to a foreign key field. and the base table has autofield which has datatype int. so maybe because of this, the issue is happening.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce that. What does `python manage.py sqlmigrate <app_label> <migration_name>` give?

Comment: @aaron I'll run the command update the output in the question.

Comment: @aaron I have updated the question with sqlmigrate command, so it is actually creating the table with forigenkey field as big int.

so temporarily what we did was we asked the DBA team to change the existing table primary key field big int in their database. So when I ran the migrate command it successfully ran and created the table.. but it's not an actual fix.

Comment: I still couldn't reproduce that.

Comment: Right now, in order to apply the migration we asked the data engineering team to change the data type in their table, and after that the migrate command successfully ran. I will try to reproduce the issue when I get time. thank you!